# why child state value is not updating in parent callback function at first time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

why child state value is not updating in parent callback function at first time? i want to make my input-Field disable based on state.

Sandbox with full example: https://z3wu6.csb.app/

Comment: Are you referring to the `console.log(edit);` right after `setEdit(edit);` in `UserProfile`? Please provide more details about issue, any debugging you've done, reproduction steps, and include the relevant code with issue here.

Comment: please refere https://z3wu6.csb.app/ link with full implementation i have made.
I want to simply make input-text  disable/enable based on state, on initial render when we click on button state not updating but after 1st click its working fine...  can you edit my sandbox or suggest where i m making mistake.

Comment: I did... but you should ***still*** provide these details... It's not our job to sift through your entire codebase to debug your code, i.e. SO isn't a free debugging service. Make it easy for someone spending free time trying to help you.

Comment: please check my above reply for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

PageHeader

Initial state is `true`, when you click the the button the `editViewHandler` is called. It toggles the `edit` state of ***this*** component but then calls the `editCallback` callback with the ***current*** value of `edit` which is initially `true`. You're sending the non-updated value to the callback! (*you set it to `true` again in `UserProfile`*) You can fix this by also inverting the `edit` value sent to `editCallback`.

```
const [edit, setEditView] = useState(true);

const editViewHandler = () => {
  setEditView(!edit);
  editCallback(!edit); // <-- send the same value you update state to
};
```

I see you've also duplicated this `edit` state in `UserProfile`. You shouldn't duplicate state. You want a single source of truth.

You already pass `editCallback` from `UserProfile` so just attach *that* as the callback to the button.

## Suggestion Solution

Toggle the value in the source callback in `UserProfile`

```
const UserProfile = () => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(true);

  const editCallback = () => setEdit(edit => !edit);

  return (
    <>
      <PageHeader
        button
        editCallback={editCallback}
        title="User Profile"
        subtitle="Overview"
      />
      <UserAccountDetails edit={edit} />
    </>
  );
};
```

And attach to button's `onClick` handler

```
const PageHeader = ({ title, subtitle, button, editCallback }) => (
  <div className="page-header py-4 withBtn d-flex align-items-center">
    {button ? <Button onClick={editCallback}>Edit Detail</Button> : null}
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit stoic-night-puu8m]

Comment: Thanks Drew for your valuable time, yes now its working.. 
just one question  about my code in Page Header File

const [edit, setEditView] = useState(true);

const editViewHandler = () => {
  setEditView(!edit);
  editCallback(edit); // <-- why this value not updating, after click function as my code just beneath the updated value
};

Comment: @Roy When you `setEditView(!edit)` to toggle the value, it hasn't toggled in state yet when you `editCallback(edit)` on the next line, it's still the same value all during the *current* render cycle, i.e. it won't *actually* toggle from `true` to `false` until the function completes and react then updates state and rerenders. You invert the value to update state, so sending the same inverted value to the callback is *more* correct. It's the same reason you can't console.log the *new* state value right after updating it.